# Can we set a list of discovery nodes?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

When starting a new node we have to indicate the address of a root node so as it can connect and discover the network.
Is there a way to set a list of nodes so as the new node does not depend on a single peer?

Environment variable:
    - CORE_PEER_DISCOVERY_ROOTNODE=vp0:7051

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q:Is there a way to set a list of nodes so as the new node does not
>   depend on a single peer?

Answer: new nodes doesn't depend on a single peer and ROOTNODE can be any peer.

from [fabric protocol spec](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/protocol-spec.md#311-discovery-messages),

Upon start up, a peer runs discovery protocol if `CORE_PEER_DISCOVERY_ROOTNODE` is specified.

`CORE_PEER_DISCOVERY_ROOTNODE` is the IP address of another peer on the network **(any peer)** that serves as the starting point for discovering all the peers on the network.

Comment: @MarcCampora, you can set `CORE_PEER_DISCOVERY_ROOTNODE` dynamically as a list of IP:PORT,IP:PORT, 
please read this, https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-245

Comment: Thanks I'll try the list setting. The feature request is interesting as well.